# Autocomplete for textbox in mvc

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, autocomplete

This is my view and controller. I have converted code from c# to vb the code was working perfectly in C# but i dont know why this java script is not working in vb. I started debugging but controllers never get called when i type something in search box.

Code for View

```
@ModelType  PrudentHealthCare.Product
@Code
    Layout = Nothing
End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        @Using (Html.BeginForm())
            @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.id)
            @<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for a product" required />
            @<input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit" />
        End Using
    </div>
</body>
</html>


<link href="~/Content/AutoComplete/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Content/AutoComplete/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/AutoComplete/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.RouteUrl( "DefaultApi" , New With { .httproute = "", .controller = "ProductApi" })';
    $('#search').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { query: request.term },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Description,
                            value: item.Id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#search').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#Id').val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
</script>
```

ProductApiController

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Namespace Controllers
    Public Class ProductApiController
        Inherits Controller

        <HttpGet>
        Public Function GetProducts(Optional query As String = "") As IEnumerable(Of Product)
            Dim xyz As String
            xyz = query
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Have you checked browser console to see if there is any error?

Comment: Nope i have not check that. How to check if javascript is working good or not with help of browser console. I have firebug but i dont think it does this kind of stuff

Comment: You can do it on firefox. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)

Answer (score 5):

jQuery UI has an [AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) widget. The autocomplete widget is quite nice and straight forward to use. In this post, how to integrate the AutoComplete widget with an ASP.NET MVC application.

The first step is to add the jQuery scripts and styles. With ASP.NET MVC 4, the following code does the work:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")    
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Using the AutoComplete widget is also simple. You will have to add a textbox and attach the AutoComplete widget to the textbox. The only parameter that is required for the widget to function is source. For this example, we will get the data for the AutoComplete functionality from a MVC action method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#tags').autocomplete(
    {
        source: '@Url.Action("TagSearch", "Home")'
});
})
```

In the above code, the textbox with id=tags is attached with the AutoComplete widget. The source points to the URL of TagSearch action in the HomeController: /Home/TagSearch. The HTML of the textbox is below:

```
<input type="text" id="tags" />
```

When the user types some text in the textbox, the action method - TagSearch is called with a parameter in the request body. The parameter name is term. So, your action method should have the following signature:

```
public ActionResult TagSearch(string term)
     {
// Get Tags from database
string[] tags = { "ASP.NET", "WebForms", 
                "MVC", "jQuery", "ActionResult", 
                "MangoDB", "Java", "Windows" };
 return this.Json(tags.Where(t => t.StartsWith(term)), 
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```