# Internal Server Error with MVC and Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an ajax designed to auto finish a text box:

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var param = { movie_name: $('#txtSearch').val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetMovieTitles',
                data: param,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

the web method is in the Home controller

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<String> GetMovieTitles(string movie_name)
    {
        MbdbContext db = new MbdbContext();

        List<string> MovieTitle = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in db.Movies.Where(m => m.MovieName.Contains(movie_name)).ToList())
        {
            MovieTitle.Add(item.MovieName.ToString());
        }

        return MovieTitle;
    }
}
```

I keep getting an internal server error. Is there anything obvious that I am missing? Where should I be looking?

Comment: It should have an exception details

Comment: it says "local hosts says: internal server error"

if i hunt some information down in f12 - > I find "failed to load the resource http://localhost/Home/GetMovieTitles" Server responded with a status of 500

Comment: Are you really coding in `MVC`? Why do you need `WebMethod`? It is for ASPX pages

Comment: I am coding in MVC, i did the webmethod because it worked for me before when i did a web forms project (honestly dont know much about it)

Comment: the way ASPX works and MVC works is entirely diferent; It is nothing new in MVC and you can Google "how to create autocomplete textbox in MVC" to start with

Comment: Removing it does not fix the issue

Comment: kk, ill do that! thank you tech.

Comment: It is not above removing `WebMethod`.  You need to change your approach for this task... Try googling some topics and come back here with a new post if you have any issue

Comment: put a break point inside GetMovieTitles method and see if it breaks. If not then we need the error on the server side

Comment: quick results I got from Google - [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/746697/Auto-Complete-TextBox-Using-jQuery-and-ASP-NET-MVC) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605278/autocomplete-for-textbox-in-mvc)

Comment: And you shouldn't return any data from MVC directly. I don't think MVC would like it. Any json data should be returned in web API. That's probably why

Comment: Just a thought.  Can you set a debug point in your web method just to see if you application gets that far?

Comment: @Steve An MVC controller can return any content you want, including json. Why else would there be a [`System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx) class?

Comment: @JasonP you are going to get an error message telling you shouldn't return data directly if you don't mark it as JsonResult if I remember right

Answer (score 1):

`[WebMethod]` attribute is designed to expose XML Web Service Method (old ASP way)

You don't need it since you using MVC.

```
[HttpPost] //since you using POST
public JsonResult GetMovieTitles(string movie_name)
{
    MbdbContext db = new MbdbContext();
    //also, it's better refactor to that way:
    List<string> MovieTitle = db.Movies
       .Where(m => m.MovieName.Contains(movie_name))
       .Select(x=>x.MovieName.ToString()).ToList()

    return Json(MovieTitle);
}
```

This way you won't iterate you collection in memory, only in DB.

Answer (score 0):

For Ajax calls in an MVC application I use the return type of JsonResult instead of List, etc.

Since your returning your content as JSON

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

You may want to try structuring your web method like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetMovieTitles(string movie_name)
{
    MbdbContext db = new MbdbContext();

    List<string> MovieTitle = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in db.Movies.Where(m => m.MovieName.Contains(movie_name)).ToList())
    {
        MovieTitle.Add(item.MovieName.ToString());
    }

    return Json(MovieTitle, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**You Don't Need to use [WebMethod] in MVC**

**Use.**

```
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("GetMovieTitles")',
//Your Code.
})
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe the conversion from List of string to List of String fails. Try to change the return type of the method.

```
public List<String> GetMovieTitles ....
```

To

```
public List<string> GetMovieTitles ...
```

Comment: 100% sure string and String are interchangeable

Comment: Yeah ok. I didn't knew. Thank you. But it's worth a try

Comment: Yeah, a string is an object of type String. Same as that int is an object of type Int32.