# Autocomplete works with sample data but fails with real data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have a really weird issue where I am trying to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605278/autocomplete-for-textbox-in-mvc) into my project. It's a simple autocomplete textbox using JQuery UI.

When I copy the exact code from that answer it works perfectly, but I need to build my list of options from database, so this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult TagSearch(string term)
{
    var a = new Access();
    var supplierNames = a.GetSuppliers().Select(s => s.SupplierName).ToArray();
    return this.Json(supplierNames.Where(t => t.StartsWith(term)),
                   JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If I step through the code I can see that `supplierNames` is a `string[]` with about 550 items. However, when I enter a `term` value into the textbox, no dropdown appears.

I tried breaking the controller down into

```
    var a = new Access();
var supplierNames = a.GetSuppliers().Select(s => s.SupplierName).ToArray();
var tags = supplierNames.Where(t => t.StartsWith(term)).ToArray();
return this.Json(tags,
   JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But when I reach the line `var tags = supplierNames.Where(t => t.StartsWith(term)).ToArray();` the debugger just stops (as in the site is stil running, but I can no longer step though), and still no autocomplete options appear.

How is this possible? Why does it work fine if I pass in an array as per the linked question, but when I pass in my array of 550 strings it just fails without any error?

See this screenshot of me stepping through the code, and it looks like it should work, but the UI fails to show me a list of options:

[image]

View:

```
<input type="text" id="tags" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tags').autocomplete(
        {
            source: '@Url.Action("TagSearch", "Supplier")'
        });
    })
</script>
```

### Update

when I build the `string[]` only using the first 10 items with

```
var supplierNames = a.GetSuppliers().Select(s => s.SupplierName).Take(10).ToArray();
```

it does work, so it seems to be somehow related to the size of the array, which is weird because its not like the whole arra is being passed back to the view.

I added this to my config file

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <!-- Update this value to change the value to 
                    a larger value that can accommodate your JSON 
                    strings -->
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="86753090" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

And also tried changing the return value to

```
return new JsonResult()
{
    Data = tags,
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
    MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue // Use this value to set your maximum size for all of your Requests
};
```

but nothing is working.

### Update 2

As mentioned in the comments, it seems the error is occurring on the line where I call `StartsWith()`. I determined this by removing `ToArray()` and checking the contents of `tags.ResultsView.Message`, which shows

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Still not sure why this is happening though

Comment: You need to show your script.

Comment: Try changing, the return type in the controller action to `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added it but it is exactly the same as the linked question. Also the fact that it works with the sample data is weird to me. I'm about to test with the real data but taking a smaller subset

Comment: @BarryO'Kane That didn't help, but calling the data with `var supplierNames = a.GetSuppliers().Select(s => s.SupplierName).Take(20).ToArray();` did work, so it's something to do with the fact that the array is too big...

Comment: Strange. There's apparently no limit on the number of results, but something's clearly happening. You could limit it from firing unti maybe 3 chars have been entered in the textbox, that should help as well.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane ye it doesn't make any senese to me because its not like the whole array gets passed back, its only used in the controller. seems to work at array size 250 as well, but fails at 500

Comment: It seems like your exceeding the allowed max length for your json request (you can increase it in the `web.config` file or set `MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue` of the `JsonResult`)

Comment: See [this article](http://rion.io/2013/04/28/handling-larger-json-string-values-in-net-and-avoiding-exceptions/) for more detail. But a user wont be able to absorb that many items in the dropdown anyway, so suggest you configure the autocomplete to require at least 2 characters before calling the server so that a manageable set of results is returned

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added `<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>` to my config but it doesn't seem to have worked. I don't really get this because I'm only passing a few values back to the view aren't I? (rather than all 550) Even when I paste `Mazilla` into the box, it fails to show any options, even though only one option should get returned

Comment: Sorry, I may have been confused by your statement _but when I pass in my array of 550 strings_ - how may items are actually being returned? (you should be using your 2nd code snippet so you can check the count of `tags`  when debugging)

Comment: Note also that your do not need to use `.ToArray()` anywhere in your controller code - it can simply be `var tags = a.GetSuppliers().Select(x => x.SupplierName).Where(x => x.StartsWith(term));`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ye I was just trying to emulate the original code as closely as possible (but the 2nd `ToArray` seems to break everything). When I debug with the full dataset and input term `Ma`, the results view of `tags` has a `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` error... However when calling `Take(10)` on the data first, I get only 1 result and it works. So seems the error is occurring on the line `StartsWith()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160188/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-bassie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this was a matter of data integrity, as there was a single record in the `Suppliers` which had a `SupplierName` value of `NULL`.

This means that when I called `StartsWith()` it must have thrown the null reference exception when it reached that record (its weird to me that linq isn't more informative about this, or that it can't just handle a null value has returning false).

So a simple resolution for this is to just change my data call to

```
var supplierNames = a.GetSuppliers()
    .Select(s => s.SupplierName)
    .Where(s => s != null).ToArray();
```

And it now works perfectly.